# How to set a client-side query execution timeout using psycopg?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg3, pep249

Is there a client-side socket/query timeout setting for psycopg? I would like to limit my query execution time so that queries run against a database that is experiencing an outage will timeout instead of running indefinitely. I need a client-side mechanism instead of a server-side mechanism so that the query can be cut off even if the database is experiencing an outage. If there is not a socket timeout setting, is there another way that I could get this behavior?

Using `statement_timeout` or Postgres's `pg_cancel_backend` function to cancel the query from another thread are not valid solutions for me because they both are server-side settings/operations. If the database is experiencing an outage it will not be able to enforce the statement_timeout setting or accept a pg_cancel_backend call.

I looked at the psycopg and PEP249 documentation and was not able to find any way to set a socket timeout. I have some experience with JDBC drivers and the JDBC interface defines a [setNetworkTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setNetworkTimeout-java.util.concurrent.Executor-int-) method to achieve this functionality. Is there a reason why PEP249 does not have an equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg/discussions/676), there is not a client-side query timeout